# SQLAlchemy-Marshmallow slow to query and serialize to JSON

Tags: python, json, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I am somewhat new to this, so if someone can help me, that would be awesome.

So I have some models set up in SQLAlchemy for a Flask app I am working on.  I populated the db (currently SQLite) with some fake data while I am building the app and am kind of surprised how slow one of my calls is.

I have a table in the DB called Menu.  The menu has a child, sections, which has a child, items. like this:

- Menu

  - Sections

    - Items

The object I am querying is, 1 Menu, which has 4 Sections, which each have 10 items.

In my Flask route, I query the DB using Menu.query.get(id) and serialize it to JSON with marshmallow.

Whole thing is taking 250ms give or take to return on my local machine.

So my question(s) is/are:
I am I being stupid in worrying about 250ms?
What is the culprit for the slowness?
 - Poor schema design?
 - SQLite / Using a SQL Db?
 - Something else?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Additionally.  I originally had 2 more levels deeper (items have options which have choices), but it was taking about a full second to complete, so I moved those to a separate endpoint for when the user requests a specific Item.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would agree that 250ms is excessive, given that everything is local. I expect that the cause of the slowness is that multiple SQL queries are being executed in order to build the JSON.

Setting `SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = True` on the SQLAlchemy configuration will show you the SQL queries being generated and confirm this.

You haven't provided your DB Models but you may find that your relationships are being lazy loaded and therefore a new SQL query is being made for each object in the tree. You can find more information in the [Relationship Loading Techniques](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html) section of the SQLAlchemy documentation.

Setting `lazy='joined'` on the child relationship (i.e. Menu -> Section and Section -> Items) will cause the child relationship to be eagerly loaded using a JOIN instead of the default SELECT.

Comment: they are being lazy loaded.  i will change over to joined and see if there is any improvement.  thanks.

Comment: wow. that certainly helped. down to 50-75ms on that change.  just curious, any drawbacks on eager loading vs lazy?

Comment: The database will be performing a JOIN so will be doing more work, but if you know the data is required by the query then it's the most efficient way to get the data (vs performing a separate 'lazy' query). Alternatively you can have the default as lazy loading and use the joinedload() option on queries that you want the join.